# Redirect standard input (read-host) to a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Here's a sample powershell script:

```
$in = read-host -prompt "input"
write-host $in
```

Here's a sample 'test.txt' file:

```
hello
```

And we want to pass *piped* input to it from powershell.  Here's some I have tried:

```
.\test.ps1 < test.txt
.\test.ps1 < .\test.txt
.\test.ps1 | test.txt
.\test.ps1 | .\test.txt
test.txt | .\test.ps1
.\test.txt | .\test.ps1
get-content .\test.txt | .\test.ps1
```

even just trying to echo input doesn't work either:

```
echo hi | \.test.ps1
```

Every example above that doesn't produce an error always prompts the user instead of accepting the piped input.

**Note**: My powershell version table says 4.0.-1.-1

Thanks

**Edit/Result:** To those looking for a solution, you cannot pipe input to a powershell script.  You have to update your PS file.  See the snippets below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your script `\.test.ps1` is not expecting the value.

Try this:

```
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$string
)

# Edit: added if statement
if($string){
    $in = "$string"
}else{
    $in = read-host -prompt "input"
}

Write-Host $in
```

Alternatively, you can use the magic variable `$input` without a `param` part (I don't fully understand this so can't really recommend it):

```
Write-Host $input
```

Comment: So one would have to edit the PS1 file to support piped input.  Is there no way to redirect the standard input?  For example, in C# you can simply Console.ReadLine() and you can pipe to that through CMD.  You won't be passing any parameters to the executable, you would be redirecting input.

Comment: @Peanut there may be a way to get what you're after that's beyond the scope of my knowledge. The [`Read-Host` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) specifies that it does not accept values from the pipeline. To get the _functionality_ you're after, I would use an `if` statement. To redirect input to PowerShell, I believe there needs to be something aside from `Read-Host` in the script

Comment: thanks for looking into it.  I didn't see the huge note stating "You cannot pipe input to this cmdlet."

Comment: Just use `$input` -- If you put `Write-Host $input` in your script, it will literally print `System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple`

Comment: `$input` works if you are piping input to .test.ps1, but if you just run `$ .test.ps1` from the shell it won't prompt for you to type anything the way that `$ cat` will.

Answer (score 5):

You can't pipe input to `Read-Host`, but there should be no need to do so.

PowerShell doesn't support input redirection (`<`) yet. In practice this is not a (significant) limitation because `a < b` can be rewritten as `b | a` (i.e., send output of `b` as input to `a`).

PowerShell can prompt for input for a parameter if the parameter's value is missing and it is set as a mandatory attribute. For example:

```
function test {
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $TheValue
  )
  "You entered: $TheValue"
}
```

If you don't provide input for the `$TheValue` parameter, PowerShell will prompt for it.

In addition, you can specify that a parameter accepts pipeline input. Example:

```
function test {
  param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [String] $TheValue
  )
  process {
    foreach ( $item in $TheValue ) {
      "Input: $item"
    }
  }
}
```

So if you write

```
"A","B","C" | test
```

The function will output the following:

```
Input: A
Input: B
Input: C
```

All of this is spelled out pretty concisely in the PowerShell documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the snippets.  I agree on the 'no need to do so', but in some certain cases we have a powershell file that we don't want to update, because that would cause QA to need to re-certify it.  Such is life.

Comment: `<` doesn't work in PowerShell for input redirection, so you don't really have a choice on that.

Comment: `a < b` and `b | a` are not equivalent in any shell scripting syntax i know of. Do you mean something like `cat b | a` or `TYPE b | a`?

Comment: Read it more generically. `a < b` (i.e., use content or output of `b` as input for `a`) is functionally equivalent to `b | a` (i.e., use content or output of `b` as input for `a`).

Comment: Ugh, in practice, this is not true that "you shouldn't need to". Take for example: `PS C:\> diff.exe -ayl <(Write-Output ($OriginalObject | Convert-JSON -Depth 99)) <(Write-Output ($UpdatedObject | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 99))`, where Write-Output here is analogous to echo (echo is an Alias for Write-Output). This doesn't work because stdin redirection is not possible, but this is a common thing that can be d one in *nix shells such as bash.

Comment: The question isn't whether PowerShell is feature-for-feature compatible with some other shell; the point is that you can accomplish a similar result, albeit in a slightly different way. (Also, not sure why you need diff.exe when PowerShell already has `Compare-Object.`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes;  in Powershell 5.1   "<"  is not implemented (which sucks)

so, this won't work:   tenkeyf < c:\users\marcus\work\data.num

but,

this will:  type c:\users\marcus\work\data.num | tenkeyf

...

Comment: ...which is exactly what I already wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell doesn’t have a redirection mechanism, but.NET have.

you can use [System.Diagnostics.Process] implements the purpose of redirecting input.

The relevant Microsoft documents are as follows.

[Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0)

This is a sample program that works perfectly on my windows 10 computer

```
function RunAndInput{
    $pi = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]::new()
    $pi.FileName ="powershell"
    $pi.Arguments = """$PSScriptRoot\receiver.ps1"""
    $pi.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pi.RedirectStandardInput = $true
    $pi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true

    $p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pi)

    $p.StandardInput.WriteLine("abc"+ "`r`n");
    $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $p.Kill()
}
```

```
RunAndInput
```

```
# OutPut

Please enter the information: abc
Received:abc
```

```
# receiver.ps1
('Received:' + (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the information'))
```

Hope to help you!